# How to create a validation list for range exceeding 255 characters

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, dropdown

Initially I did not know why my Excel file kept getting corrupted but after much research, I realised that it's because my Data Validation drop-down list has more than 255 characters. "A comma separated data validation list that exceeds 255 characters (including commas) will corrupt a workbook"

This was my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E12:E21")) Is Nothing Then

Dim col As New Collection
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim dvlist As String

'Loop thru the data range i.e. these are the cells used for the validation list. Very long list.
For Each rng In Sheet2.Range("B2:B249 , D2:D19")
'ignore blanks
    If Len(Trim(rng.Value)) <> 0 Then
        'create a unique list
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add rng.Value, CStr(rng.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next rng

'concatenate with "," as the delimiter
For i = 1 To col.Count
    dvlist = dvlist & col.Item(i) & ","
Next i

'add it to the DV
With Sheet1.Range("E12:E21").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=dvlist
End With

End If


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F12:F21")) Is Nothing Then

'Loop thru the data range i.e. these are the cells used for the validation list. Very long list.
For Each rng In Sheet2.Range("A2:A249")
'ignore blanks
    If Len(Trim(rng.Value)) <> 0 Then
        'create a unique list
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add rng.Value, CStr(rng.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next rng

'concatenate with "," as the delimiter
For i = 1 To col.Count
    dvlist1 = dvlist1 & col.Item(i) & ","
Next i

'add it to the DV
With Sheet1.Range("F12:F21").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=dvlist1
End With


End If


End Sub
```

As you can see, my list is very long and it has spaces in between the list that because of reasons, cannot be removed. Hence, I am unable to use data validation function in Excel. Is there any way I can go around this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can print that in a Range on the Sheet and set that range as the Validation Range. Also, it will be good if you can give feedback on your previous questions :)

Comment: Hey @Mikku, hmm..but the range is already the validation list. And I knowww.., so sorry because I'm still testing it out so I dont want to give a rash response to your answer in the other thread. I willl respond once the code is confirm! My apologies

Comment: As currently I am unsure if the code truly works due to this error

Comment: See either you can create a Contiguous Range to supply in Data Validation, because it doesn't take functions like `Union` of ranges, or you can pass a string. But as you have already figured out that string is not working, you can Print your `Col` in a corner of the Sheet and add that range to the Validation List.

Comment: What version of Excel?  I believe the 255 character limit does not apply to generated lists starting with 2007.  BUT, there was a bug in 2007 that resulted in a problem if you saved your workbook as `.xlsm` vs `.xlsb`. `Excel found unreadable content` --> the list was deleted.  Or you could use a contiguous range on the worksheet for your validation list. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99a03916-cbce-4e4b-8aca-94636ff952e3/data-validation-list-from-string-ok-when-saved-as-xlsb-unreadable-when-saved-as-xlsm?forum=isvvba) for more discussion.

Comment: @Mikku hello Mikku, sorry I was outside and didnt have my laptop. If thats the case, should I just simply copy past the values to a corner of my sheet and use the excel data validation function?

Comment: Yes That should work.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hello Ron, thank you, I looked through your discussion and I'm still trying to comprehend it and apply it to my situation as well. I noticed that you used `Set r = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))` and `Set r = Range("D2:D5200")`. How come r can be set twice? Sorry I'm still learning about VBA

Comment: @Mikku I did that Mikku! thank you

Comment: A variable can be assigned a value as many times as you want. Depends on what you are using it for at the time. Isn't this true in most programming languages?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this issue myself, I have figured out that the easiest way to handle this is actually to delete the validation list before saving or changing the validation list to below 255 characters.

The excel file only corrupts when saving and re-opening the file. Below is an example of deleting the validation list before saving.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

     CellWithValidationList.Validation.Delete

End Sub
```

Of course, this assumes that you already have VBA code that automatically recreates the validation list upon some event after opening the file.